# Replace Script only gets the first instance and not all

Tags: jquery

As the title says. The code that is used is not replacing all instances of the company's name. The website is using foundation and if I paste the script in the different section's it works.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").children().each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Oblique Creation Inc.", "Obl<span style='color:red;'>i</span>que Creation Inc."));
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript replace function, when using a string as the first parameter, [only replaces the first occurrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) of that string.

Instead, use a regular expression:

```
$(this).html().replace(/Oblique Creation Inc/g, "Obl<span style='color:red;'>i</span>que Creation Inc");
```